# Skipped testcases while using pytest-dependency across modules

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest-dependency, pytest-order

Been learning Pytest recently and got stuck with the [sample code](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scope.html#dependencies-in-session-scope) from the documentation. Just made a few changes on the code with the aim of making all testcases pass but looks like the one's with dependency from test_mod_01 tend to be skipped. Not sure where I doing wrong

Code Structure

```
  TestOrderDependencies
        -- test_mod_01.py
        -- test_mod_02.py
```

test_mod_01.py

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.dependency(name="a")
def test_a():
    pass


@pytest.mark.dependency(name="b")
# @pytest.mark.xfail(reason="deliberate fail")
def test_b():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.dependency(name="c", depends=["a"])
def test_c():
    pass


class TestClass(object):

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name="b", depends=["c"])
    def test_b(self):
        pass
```

test_mod_02.py

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.dependency(name="a")
# @pytest.mark.xfail(reason="deliberate fail")
def test_a():
    assert True


@pytest.mark.dependency(name="e",
                        depends=["TestOrderDependencies/test_mod_01.py::a",
                                 "TestOrderDependencies/test_mod_01.py::c"],
                        scope='session'
                        )
def test_e():
    pass


@pytest.mark.dependency(name="f",
                        depends=["TestOrderDependencies/test_mod_01.py::b",
                                 "TestOrderDependencies/test_mod_02.py::e"],
                        scope='session'
                        )
def test_f():
    pass


@pytest.mark.dependency(name="g",
                        depends=["TestOrderDependencies/test_mod_01.py::TestClass::b"],
                        scope='session'
                        )
def test_g():
    pass
```

Output

```
rootdir: /Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/TestOrderDependencies
plugins: order-1.2.0, dependency-0.5.1
collected 8 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

test_mod_01.py::test_a PASSED
test_mod_01.py::test_b PASSED
test_mod_01.py::test_c PASSED
test_mod_01.py::TestClass::test_b PASSED
test_mod_02.py::test_a PASSED
test_mod_02.py::test_e SKIPPED (test_e depends on TestOrderDependencies/test_mod_01.py::a)
test_mod_02.py::test_f SKIPPED (test_f depends on TestOrderDependencies/test_mod_01.py::b)
test_mod_02.py::test_g SKIPPED (test_g depends on TestOrderDependencies/test_mod_01.py::TestClass::b)

================================================================================================== 5 passed, 3 skipped in 0.03s ====
```

1. I have tried to look at similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69166125/session-scope-with-pytest-dependency) and followed the suggestions
2. Also tried utilizing pytest-order.
3. Tried to downgrade my python from 3.11 - 3.10.

With these attempts i could not make it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I use your test code, I get unknown dependencies "tests/test_mod_01.py::test_c" and "tests/test_mod_02.py::test_e". This is correct, as these don't exist. If I correct the names (replace "tests" with "TestOrderDependencies"), all tests pass, because they are alreay correctly ordered, regardless of `pytest-order`. Is that a typo in your actual tests, or didn't you copy them correctly?

Comment: Ah, and judging by your output, you run the tests from the `TestOrderDependencies` directory, so this one shouldn't figure in the test name. You can just copy the test names as shown in the test output to be on the sure side. I guess your whole problem is that you got the dependent test names wrong. If you are struggling with the correct test names, you could also give the dependent tests a name (e.g. `@pytest.mark.dependency(name="myName")`) and use this name as the dependency.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thank you. Yeah, the naming was not correct. I fixed that. I also followed your advise on naming testcases but didnot resolve the issue. Here is link to code in [GitHub](https://github.com/WaleWalex/TestOrderDependencies.git). You can have a look at it.

Comment: You are not using the test names as they are. Just use the names without any scope.

Comment: In case you missed it: I had made a PR for youe example in GitHub that shows how it should work.